# Why does relaxation/meditaion help when you have cold feet/hands?

Tags: meditation

Sometimes when I'm cold and by cold I mean I have cold feet and hands I sit and mediate for a few minutes (usualy for about 15min). After few minutes I feel how my feet and hands become bit by bit warmer and I'm not cold anymore.

Could you explain how this works and why? It has always been fascinating me.

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly due to your blood pressure. High blood pressure can cause ineffective blood perfusion which could be the cause of your cold hands and feets. The meditation/relaxing could be lowering your blood pressure and therefore increasing blood perfusion throughout the tissues.

[Complaints of cold extremities among patients on antihypertensive treatment](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/6136158)

> It is concluded that cold hands and feet are common among
>   hypertensive patients and may be aggravated by treatment with not only
>   beta-blockers but also diuretics

And while the above article talks about hypertensive patients, it was just a example of how high blood pressure can affect your extremities temperature.

[Anxiety and Cold feet:](http://www.calmclinic.com/anxiety/symptoms/cold-feet)

- This can occur via the fight-flight mechanism. Which overall means less blood flow to feet and hands.

> Anxiety also causes blood to flow into your heart and trunk muscles.

- > Anxiety also can lead to faster breathing and hyperventilation.
  >   Hyperventilation causes blood vessels to constrict, which slows down
  >   blood flow dramatically.
- > Sweating is designed to cool down your body so that you don't overheat
  >   when you run away. Unfortunately, since there is no danger, you simply
  >   start to sweat, and your feet are often the area that sweat a great
  >   deal and are prone to feeling cold more than other areas of the body.